# Нужна ваша помощь

Tags: javascript

**Реализуйте и экспортируйте по умолчанию функцию, которая высчитывает сумму всех элементов массива, которые делятся без остатка на 3 (три). В случае пустого массива функция должна вернуть 0 (для этого в коде можно использовать guard expression):**
Примеры

```
const coll1 = [8, 9, 21, 19, 18, 22, 7];
calculateSum(coll1); // 48
 
const coll2 = [2, 0, 17, 3, 9, 15, 4];
calculateSum(coll2); // 27

const coll = [];
calculateSum(coll); // 0
```

Мой код

```
export default calculateSum = (coll) => {
  let sum = coll[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < coll.length; i += 1) {
    if (coll[i] % 3 === 0) {
      sum += coll[i];
    }
    return sum;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Ответ получается 17 и 2, а нужно 48 и 0

Comment: написал что не так в моем коде(((

Comment: внес, в вопрос внес код, или его не видно?

Comment: Отладка вам поможет (ссылка вверху)......... кстати `let sum = coll[0];` - это неправильно.... т.к. во-первых первого элемента может не быть, а во-вторых оно может не делиться на 3 без остатка

Comment: В целом ошибка видна........но я не стану говорить, т.к. хочу, чтобы вы, как специалист, освоили отладку и увидели причину сами

Comment: в чем ошибка то

Comment: Вы не внимательно читаете комментарии. Перечитайте.

Comment: @addict1337 Смотрите пояснение Алексея и обратите внимание на `return` в цикле, он возвращает результат функции, в циклах возвратов нет.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar эх, ну зачем?))

Comment: все сделал спасибо большое)